# Given the index number, computing the row/column

Tags: arrays, math, matrix

This is partly related to maths, but since I'm doing it in VB.NET (and because a programmer knows maths but a mathematician may not know programming :)), I'm more likely to get a quicker answer here:

I'm printing images in a tabular format. Each page has M rows and N columns. If the number of images exceeds what can be accommodated on one page, we move on to next page and so on. The problem here is, given the index number of an image, what is the shortest expression that would give me the zero-based row / column of the image (ignorant of the page number on which it will fall)?

After spending some time, I have come up with the following, but it doesn't handle some corner cases (`M` is number of columns, `N` is number of rows, `Index` is 1-based):

```
Dim R = (Index - Index Mod (M * N)) \ M - 1 
Dim C = Index Mod M
```

N.B. The printing goes from left-to-right first and then to next row.

Comment: @Downvoter. Comments?

Comment: (I didn't downvote) Consired removing `.net` and `vb.net` tags, as this question can be applied to any language/framework.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Consider MOD and \

Comment: Yes, they are .net specific however they yield incorrect results and are overcomplicated - thus irrelevant.

Comment: Removed the tags. However I do not agree to overcomplicated thing. They have better readability and faster execution (no function call overhead).

Comment: Ok, overcomplication is a subjective matter. However be careful about speed claims. And, speed is probably completely irrelevant here as the difference will hardly be noticeable in your solution (critical tasks are probably related to image manipulation). Nevertheless this equation can be written with more general notation, so it doesn't have to refer to any specific platform. But it just a simple suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'll redefine the notation:

```
rowCount = N
columnCount = M
```

If page is irrelevant, then first alter the `index` to be page-ignorant:

```
pageSize = rowCount * columnCount
index = index % pageSize
```

Then, if you're iterating rows first (by this I mean then when the `index` moves, it goes to the next column - so it slides along a row, and at the end of the row it goes to the next row) then:

```
rowNumber = floor(index / columnCount)
columnNumber = index - rowNumber * columnCount
```

Examples with last index for `2x3` grid:

```
rowCount = 2
columnCount = 3
```

```
page1
 c0 c1 c2
----------
|0 |1 |2 | r0
---------- 
|3 |4 |5 | r1
----------
page2
 c0 c1 c2
----------
|6 |7 |8 | r0
----------
|9 |10|11| r1
----------
```

when `index = 5` then:

```
pageSize = 2*3 = 6
index = 5 % 6 = 5
rowNumber = floor(5 / 3) = 1
columnNumber = 5 - 1 * 3 = 2
```

when `index = 11` then:

```
pageSize = 6 (as above)
index = 11 % 6 = 5
rowNumber = 1 (as above)
columnNumber = 2 (as above)
```

Comment: I'm not iterating rows first, i.e. the printing goes from left-to-right and then to next row. I'll edit my question

Comment: @dotNET Well, as you can see the difference in calculations isn't very surprising :)

Comment: Are you using `floor` to do integer division? The backslash operator does that.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of existence of this operator, however the explicit way seems more readable to me.

Comment: @dotNET We have a misunderstanding about what does "rows first" mean - I've edited the answer. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. Consider I have 1 column and 3 rows. Image No. 4 should go to 2nd page's first row, first column, i.e. the variables above should return 0, 0, but here they return 0 and 4.

Comment: Still no. Consider image no. 6 in the above configuration. Should be on 2nd page's 3rd row, first column, but your computation returns first row, first column.

Comment: @dotNET Right again. I confused `M` with `N`. This version seems to be correct regarding your examples.

Comment: Consider 2 x 3 grid and check the position of last image of each page. it is only that image that has been giving problem to me since the start.

Comment: Ok, look. This is TRIVIAL, or I'm missing something. I've added an example for 2x3 grid. It works, as well as for 2x3. Just get a pencil, a piece of paper and check for yourself...

Comment: I see. Must have been something wrong on my end. Thanks a bunch.